# Как равномерно распределить товар по пользователям

Tags: php

Есть массив с товаром и массив с пользователями, нужно равномерно присвоить`*` товар каждому пользователю

Например у нас есть 100 товаров и 4 пользователя, нам нужно 100/4 получим 25 товаров на каждого пользователя. А как быть дальше?

Получается нужно создать 1 цикл с перебором пользователей и 4 цикла с лимитом в 25?

```
    $limit = floor(count($prods)/4);
    $count = floor(count($prods)/4);
    $s = 0;
    foreach($users as $user) {
        for($i=$s; $s<$limit; $s++) {
            echo $prods[$s]['name'].'<br>';
        }
        $limit += $count;
    }
    $limit -= $count;
    echo '<br>Всего товаров:'.count($prods);
    echo '<br>Распределено:'.$limit.'<br>';
```

Возможны ли способы проще?
И + как реализовать товар в рандомном порядке?

`*` У товара есть свое поле `user_id` в него добавляется ид пользователя

UPD

Реализация `array_chunk`

```
if(count($prods) >= 4) {// Проверяем, чтобы товаров было больше чем пользователей
  $limit = ceil(count($prods)/4);//Получаем число, по сколько должно быть товара на 1 человека
  $new_prods = array_chunk($prods, $limit);
}
```

На выходе при условии, что товаров будет 10 я получил

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
            [2] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
            [2] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
            [2] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
        )
    [3] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [name] => название товара
                )
        )
)
```

Получается, что первым он дал по 3 товара, а последнему все, что осталось, то есть 1 товар и т.д

Возможно ли сделать именно равномерно, чтобы он всем дал по 2 товара, а остаток не учитывал?

Comment: Чтобы не мучаться с ручным лимитированием, я бы сделал срез по товарам через [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) или [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) и оформил присваивание в функцию `setGoods($user, $goods)`. Для рандомного порядка можно использовать перемешивание [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

Comment: @AlexKrass спасибо, можно немного поподробней про `array_chunk`, у меня не выходит. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ну вы все сделали провильно, просто вместо `ceil` надо было использовать `floor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все три примера подготовлены и проверены на следующей заготовке:

```
$goods = [];
for($i = 1, $limit = rand(10,20); $i < $limit; $i++)
    $goods[] = "товар $i";
shuffle($goods);

$users = [[],[],[],[]];

function setGoods(&$user, $goods){
    $user = $goods;
}
```

Пример 1. Используя `array_splice` (!модифицирует исходный массив!)

```
$limit = floor(count($goods)/count($users));
for($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++){
    setGoods($users[$i], array_splice($goods, 0, $limit));
}
```

Пример 2. Используя `array_chunk`

```
$chunks = array_chunk($goods, floor(count($goods)/count($users)));
for($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++){
    setGoods($users[$i], $chunks[$i]);
}
```

Пример 3. Для любителей небольшой магии, с использованием [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php) (функция setGoods заменена лямбда функцией)

```
array_walk($users, function(&$user, $key, $chunks){ 
    $user = $chunks[$key];
}, array_chunk($goods, floor(count($goods)/count($users))));
```